# Готовые программы DoS атак

Tags: ddos, безопасность

Требуются программы, осуществляющие DoS атаки, можно и тестирующие программы на уязвимость к DoS атакам.

Comment: Вот чесно. я паражаюсь.

[сссыль][1] задавал ты вопрос, получил ответ, и все равно тебе непонятно?


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/51579/%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-ddos-%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8

Comment: Во первых не dos а DDos атак, а во вторых это делается на с++ без использования сторонних программ. Через прокси и с++

Comment: @dajver не только  на c++.     это можно делать используя любой язык программирования, способный работать с сетью.

Answer (score 3):

Как ни странно, хорошая статья и ссылки есть [на луркморе](http://lurkmore.to/Low_Orbit_Ion_Cannon),

Для тестирования *ab (Apache Benchmark)* и [siege](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/webdev/65128/)(обязательно почитайте комментарии).

Answer (score 0):

**Pentium**, для этого нужен ботнет, состоящий как минимум из 1000 компьютеров. У меня есть реализация бот-клиента и бот-сервера....но вы должны понимать, что ложить на лопатки чужой сервер - уголовное дело...даже за убийство человека дают меньше =)